# Nested directives are not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a formatting directive using MomentJS that works fine on it's own. It doesn't try to maintain bindings but is only meant to spit out a formatted date. When I nest it inside of another directive, that in turn uses the ng-repeat directive, it doesn't work any more. What needs to change to allow it to render the formated date?

http://jsfiddle.net/P2cu6/3/

```
angular.module('test').directive('payPeriodDropDown', function () {
        return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            sName: '@',
            sClass: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
            $scope.timePeriods = ranges;
        },
        template: '<select name="{{sName}}" id="{{sName}}" class="{{sClass}}">' +
                '<option ng-repeat="period in timePeriods" value="{{$index}}">' +
                    '<moment-format val="{{period.start}}" format="YYYY" ng-transclude></moment-format> - ' +
                    '<moment-format val="{{period.end}}" format="YYYY" ng-transclude></moment-format>' +
                '</option>' +
            '</select>'
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant solve your problem directly, but if you would use a filter for momentFormat instead of a directive, it would work.

see http://jsfiddle.net/P2cu6/6/

```
angular.module('test').filter('momentFormat', function () {
    return function(input, format) {
            var regexEpic = /^\d+$/ig;
            var val = (regexEpic.test(input)) ? window.parseInt(input) : input;
            return moment(val).format(format);
        }
    });
```

regards

Comment: this is much cleaner solution.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I've been teaching myself Angular and hadn't reached filters yet. I like this idea a lot, as artur mentioned, that looks like a much cleaner way to implement.